# how to compare a string in if statement

Tags: java, android

i am trying to make a program which compares a string

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);

        if(inpt==null)op.setText("Please Enter");
        else  if (inpt.equals("a")) op.setText("a entered");
        else if (inpt.equals("b")) op.setText("b entered");

        else op.setText("unknown keyword");
```

but the else statement is always executed. Please help me correct this code

i am a beginner and don't know much yet.......

Comment: what is the type of `inpt` variable?

Comment: Character string like or just letters

Comment: what value and where is assigned to `inpt` variable?

Comment: Input gets its value from an edit text .. it's working because I tested it without using if

Comment: share the code which assign text from input element to string variable inpt

Comment: ok, so you're assigning text only one time, during activity creation, you don't update variable when text in input element is changed

Comment: Bro I am a beginner and I i don't know much. Can you clarify what you just said?

Comment: what do you think `final String inpt=ip.getText().toString();` does? when this line of code is executed? How many times?

Comment: It stores the  string that entered in edit text box "ip" into the string inpt

Comment: right, two questions are left

Comment: I don't know what you meant by how many times .. i ts not a loop i think it only be executed once

Comment: right, one last question

Comment: What is the last qstn?

Comment: when this line of code is executed?

Comment: I don't know that

Comment: hint: this line executed _before_ you entered anything into input element (ie it will have empty value), you already know that this action will be performed ones, effectively it means - that this variable always contains empty value. But you want to get value _after_ you entered something, so you need to execute this line of code _after_, for example just before the comparison

Comment: Do I have to place the code inside the on click listener?

Comment: yes, onclick handler will work just fine

Comment: Thanks man it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because this inpt string is declared **final**. Means value can not be change and *string* inpt have to update every time when *onClick* action is performed. Otherwise it will take the same value and gets excuted the else part. So i removed the final keyword and declared the string inside the onClick function. Try this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText ip=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ip);

    final TextView op=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op);
    //final String inpt=ip.getText().toString();


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            String inpt=ip.getText().toString();
                InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);

                if(inpt==null)op.setText("Please Enter");
                else  if (inpt.equals("a")) op.setText("a entered");
                else if (inpt.equals("b")) op.setText("b entered");

                else op.setText("Unknown keyword");

            }
        });
    }
```